# Assign variable to javascript from html or database

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

Hello i want to use counter which takes value from js file, but i want to change it.

Here is js code;

```
function countUp(count)
 {
var div_by = 100,
    speed = Math.round(count / div_by),
    $display = $('.count'),
    run_count = 1,
    int_speed = 24;

var int = setInterval(function() {
    if(run_count < div_by){
        $display.text(speed * run_count);
        run_count++;
    } else if(parseInt($display.text()) < count) {
        var curr_count = parseInt($display.text()) + 1;
        $display.text(curr_count);
    } else {
        clearInterval(int);
    }
}, int_speed);
 }

  countUp(600);
```

It counts to 600 but i want assign variable to this from database probly with codebehind.

Here is html code ;

```
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
                  <section class="panel">
                      <div class="symbol red">
                        <i class=" fa fa-times text-muted"></i>
                      </div>
                      <div class="value">
                          <h1 class="count">123123123</h1>
                          <p>Position Canceled</p>
                      </div>
                  </section>
              </div>
```

How can i change countUp value in js. Please help me.
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function countUp(count)
 {
var div_by = 100,
    speed = Math.round(count / div_by),
    $display = $('.count'),
    run_count = 1,
    int_speed = 24;

var int = setInterval(function() {
    if(run_count < div_by){
        $display.text(speed * run_count);
        run_count++;
    } else if(parseInt($display.text()) < count) {
        var curr_count = parseInt($display.text()) + 1;
        $display.text(curr_count);
    } else {
        clearInterval(int);
    }
}, int_speed);
 }



var _count=0;
```

//If you are retreiving count from database, you can perform ajax call

```
var request = $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",            
            dataType: json
        });

        request.done(function(msg) {
            _count=msg.data;            
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
```

//if you are assinging count value from html tags
eg: assign value into hidden field, then

```
<input type="hidden" id="count" value="600"/>
_count=$('#count).val();
  countUp(600);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following syntax:

```
countUp('<%= CountValueFromDB %>');
```

Where CountValueFromDB is variable you can declare in your code-behind for particular page and populate it from database or any other source in your Page_Load method or another method called during page life cycle.

Alternatively you can call RegisterStartupScript in your code behind passing "countUp(" + CountValueFromDB + ");" for 'script' parameter.